# Async functions executing out of order

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to execute the following code, however "// go do something else" keeps happening before "// do stuff with things"

It appears that my code is not waiting for mongoose.model('things').find() to finish before moving on. I've tried different variations of async/await and nothing seems to work.

Not getting errors an everything executes, just out of order.

```
const asyncFunction = async () => {
     mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://...`);
     mongoose.model('things', {data:String});
     mongoose.model('things').find((err, things)=>{
          // do stuff with things 
     }
     console.log('something'); 
}

const otherAsyncFunction = async () {
     await asyncFunction();
     // go do something else 
}
otherAsyncFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `asyncFunction` doesn't return anything, so there's no point awaiting it.
2. You have no Mongoose schema.
3. The syntax to create a Mongoose model ([doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)) is :

```
    const thingsShema = new mongoose.Schema({ data: 'string' });
    const Thing = mongoose.model('thing', thingsShema );
```

4. You are creating your model, but then your model isn't stored in a variable and you're not using it at all.
5. `mongoose.model('things')` : this line creates a new Mongoose model but you're not passing it any schema. Anyway you already did that on the previous line.
6. `.find()` is asynchronous, and you're not returning its value.
7. You aren't passing any argument to `.find()`, only a callback function.

This code should work better :

```
const asyncFunction = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://...`);
    
    const thingsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ data: 'string' });
    const Things = mongoose.model('things', thingsSchema);

    const foundThings = await Things
                                .find({}) // Query conditions (here, querying for 'everything', an empty object)
                                .lean()   // Returns simple JSON and not a collection of Mongoose objects
                                .exec();  // returns a true Promise and not just a thenable

    console.log('foundThings = ', foundThings);

    return foundThings; // this returns a Promise, because 'async' functions always do
}

const otherAsyncFunction = async () => {
    const result = await asyncFunction();

    console.log("Result = ", result); // Normally this will log the same thing as 'foundThings'


    // go do something else 
}
otherAsyncFunction();
```

Answer (score -1):

async functions return Promise object. When you exec await asyncFunction(), 'await' wait status asyncFunction() - resolve or reject.But in your code there are no resolve() or reject() functions. So you need to do like this:

```
const asyncFunction = async (resolve) => {
    mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://...`);
    mongoose.model('things', {data:String});
    mongoose.model('things').find((err, things)=>{
         // do stuff with things 
    });
    console.log('something'); 
    resolve()
}

const otherAsyncFunction = async () => {
    await asyncFunction();
    // go do something else 
}
otherAsyncFunction();
```

Comment: 1. `asyncFunction` expects to be passed a function that you call `resolve` (why??), but you don't pass it anything, so `resolve` is undefined so this code will crash. 2. You are not returning the result of the DB call.